# React refresh page after navigation clear localStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

Im using React. After login i use

```
 useNavigate from "react-router-dom";
```

> this navigate me to my home page. But my home page should re-render depends of user credentials. I store the information using localStorage. Everything working perfect but after navigate home page i use;

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate(0)
```

When i use navigate(0) it refresh page but delete everything in my localStorage. Is there any way to refresh page without clear my localStorage?

Comment: `localStorage` is not deleted by navigation. It's something else that clears your storage